# How to Correctly Configure RequireJS Shim

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I have an issue which has been confusing the heck out of me as I initially thought I understood the 'shim' configuration part of RequireJS. Using the code below I define an entry called 'app' which also happens to be the name of another script/object in the root:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts',

    shim: {
        'vendor/jquery-2.0.3.min': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'vendor/underscore-min': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'vendor/backbone': {
            deps: ['vendor/underscore-min'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'library/marionette/backbone.marionette': {
            deps: ['vendor/backbone'],
            exports: 'Marionette'
        },
        'library/backbone.stickit' : {
            deps: ['vendor/backbone'] 
        },
        'library/backbone.subroute' : {
            deps: ['vendor/backbone'],
            exports: 'Backbone.SubRoute'
        },
        'app': {
            deps: [
              'vendor/jquery-2.0.3.min', 
              'vendor/underscore-min', 
              'vendor/backbone',
              'library/backbone.stickit',
              'library/backbone.subroute',
              'library/marionette/backbone.marionette'
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

If I define a method immediately after:

```
require(['app'], function (app) { 
    app.expose('vent', _.extend({}, Backbone.Events));

    app.initialize(function () {    
      this.vent.trigger('initialized');
    });
});
```

I am able to use Backbone without having to explicitly bring it in. Why is this? Is it because I "require(['app']" immediately after in the same file?

Another aspect to this mess I've created is that any other resources I bring in:

```
require(['app', 'routers/main'], function (app, MainRouter) { 
    app.expose('vent', _.extend({}, Backbone.Events));

    app.initialize(function () {    
      new MainRouter();

      this.vent.trigger('initialized');
    });
});
```

complain about backbone being 'undefined'. So it's magically available to me from where I define app, but beyond that it's not.  I feel like I am fundamentally misunderstanding something here - please could someone set me straight?

Comment: weird but this should work...only reason i can see for it not working may be in routers/main may not be having that app required...did you BTW check if Backbone variable error coming from 2nd line only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
    'app': {
        deps: [
          'vendor/jquery-2.0.3.min', 
          'vendor/underscore-min', 
          'vendor/backbone',
          'library/backbone.stickit',
          'library/backbone.subroute',
          'library/marionette/backbone.marionette'
        ]
    }
```

Either `'app'` is not AMD-aware (it does not use `define(...)`), in which case you need an `exports` value so that RequireJS knows what `'app'` exports, or it **is** AMD-aware (the file that defines `'app'` calls (`define(...)`), in which case you don't need a shim.

Having a shim without an `exports` value is correct only for some special cases. For instance plugins that hook into something else. (Even then, the docs say you should use `exports` due to some IE limitations: see ["Note however if you want to get 404 load detection in IE..."](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config).)

(Also, this probably won't fix your problem but jQuery 1.9.1 does not need a shim so I doubt that jQuery 2.x needs one.)